# Pause Loop to allow for Coroutine / Loop to finish graphics Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am attempting to have a character move Tiles one by one to a position.  What happens is a click the position, then the code finds a path to that position and moves one tile at a time till it reaches the position.  I have the pathfinding code working and it is in an ArrayList (don't judge).  I then insert the array list into a for loop as follows:

```
//This function Moves Character to clicked location
void MoveToPosition(ArrayList Path)
{

    int s = 2;
    while (s < Path.Count)
    {
        Debug.Log(Path[s]);
        StartCoroutine(MoveToPositionBuffer((Vector3) Path[s]));
        s++;

    }
    ResetTiles();
}

//This does the continous Calculations Somehow
IEnumerator MoveToPositionBuffer(Vector3 Position)
{
    Vector3 StartingPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
    Vector3 EndPosition = Position;
    EndPosition[1] = StartingPosition[1];

    float counter = 0;

    while(counter < 1)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(StartingPosition, EndPosition, counter);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Now my main issue is that it goes through the entire loop, then does the Lerping from the start position to the end position and skips the graphics for moving from the first tile to the second tile to the third, etc.  What i need to do is pause the loop to let the first Coroutine finish before the loop continues and starts the second Coroutine (so on and so on).  I've tried a few things that i found on google (`Thread.Sleep()`, `Yield Return WaitForSeconds()` within the Coroutine), but it doesn't seem to work.... Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> What i need to do is pause the loop to let the first Coroutine finish
>   before the loop continues and starts the second Coroutine (so on and
>   so on)

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41006517/3785314) you left is incorrect. Like [AlGoreRhythm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000932/pause-loop-to-allow-for-coroutine-loop-to-finish-graphics-issue/41006517#comment69221520_41006517) stated, you are only waiting for 1 second. It may be working for you now but it is **not** reliable. You have problems of code not able to finish running when there is a huge drop in frame-rate.

Remove the `WaitForSeconds`, then use `yield return StartCoroutine(MoveToPositionBuffer((Vector3)Path[i]));`

```
IEnumerator DelayForMovingLoop(ArrayList Path)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < Path.Count; i++)
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveToPositionBuffer((Vector3)Path[i]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the methods are running on the same thread. That means, that the whole loop will be processed and the drawing will occur after it finishes. When the loop ends, that however means, that the position will be the last on the path.

To prevent this, you will have to remove the loop and move the variables outside the method and jsut move the character one step each time the update cycle happens. The move to position method could look a little like this. It will have to be called with each update as long as the `s` is less than `Path.Count`. The idea is, you have to do the loop "in steps", not all at once in one call.

```
private int s = 2;

void MoveToPosition(ArrayList Path)
{
   Debug.Log(Path[s]);
   StartCoroutine(MoveToPositionBuffer((Vector3) Path[s]));
   s++;
}
```

Comment: I attempted to do it this way.  To put it simply, I put some code in the update function and that's what decides if it should move to the next position.... but now it doesn't animate and it now teleports from each square to the next. Any Ideas?

Comment: Feature! Not a bug :)

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was put a IEnumerator Function within an IEnumerator Function that way i Could set a delay:

```
 IEnumerator DelayForMovingLoop(ArrayList Path)
{

    for (int i = 2; i < Path.Count; i++)
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveToPositionBuffer((Vector3)Path[i]));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: How does that wait for it to be finished? You're just waiting 1 second.

Comment: If you look at the while loop within the function 'MoveToPositionBuffer()', the time to travel to the next tile will always take exactly one second (can be changed later by setting 'counter < "Whatever time frame"' and dividing 'counter' in the Lerp by the same amount.  So by delaying the Next Coroutine by 1 second, it gives the first Coroutine enough time to animate moving one tile :)